# How can I discover the Phillips Hue Wifi lightbulbs on my network with nmap?

Tags: nmap, philips-hue

Phillips has these instructions (https://developers.meethue.com/develop/get-started-2/) for connecting to/playing with their Hue lights.  Apparently, they each host a small server.

I've heard/seen nmap suggested pretty much everywhere for discovering things on the local network (or networks in general).  I think this is a great chance to maybe get used to the tool, but everything I've tried is yielding zero results.

I know for a fact there's about 9 lap tops on this network, plus 3 hue lights so surely I'm doing something wrong for there to be zero results.

**How can I discover these lights using nmap?  Or is it the wrong tool?**

Comment: Nmap should work fine. Do you have any code showing how you have the scanning setup? Also are the lights getting an ip addr from the DHCP on your router?

Comment: So, you don't see any device at all or just not the light bulbs? If you don't see any device on your network this might due to security settings, e.g. depending on the scan type nmap sends for example ICMP echo requests which might never answered with an ICMP echo reply.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you have a Hue bridge for your lightbulbs. If not, let me know and I'll delete my answer

You can actually find the Hue bridge once its connected to your network using the broadcast address of your router & by using nmap and arp. I tried this on my bridge and it seems to work.  This is what I did

```
# Replace 192.168.1.255 with your network broadcast ip
$ nmap -sP 192.168.1.255/24 > /dev/null; sudo arp -na | grep "at 00:17:88"
```

This will get you the devices that have "Philips Lighting BV" vendor specific MAC segment (This was for my Hue bridge and it's a really old one). Try for the MAC segments based on your bridge and you may be successful with this.

The bridges that are connected to your network will look like this:

```
? (192.168.1.111) at 0:17:88:9:73:d2 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

After this you can actually curl the IP above and see if you get access to the web server inbuilt into the bridge.

```
$ curl 192.168.1.111
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no Hue bridge.  I setup the lightbulbs to be connected to the wifi through an app called Wiz.  But the only way they appear to be able to communicate it through the router.

Comment: But is there a way to find older an newer Hue bridges on the network? Because the MAC address of my bridge differs completly compared to yours. Maybe holding a list of all possible MAC segmets for Hue Bridges is the only solution?! 
Because i want to connect to the bridge in a maybe unknown network.